# Get columns of index on DB2

Tags: sql, indexing, db2

How can I get the columns, which an index of a table uses, in DB2?

I tried:

```sql
DESCRIBE INDEXES FOR TABLE 'MYTABLE' SHOW DETAIL;
```

But I get the error message

> ILLEGAL SYMBOL "INDEXES". SOME SYMBOLS THAT MIGHT BE LEGAL ARE: PROCEDURE PROC. SQLCODE=-104, SQLSTATE=42601, DRIVER=4.16.53

Ideally I want information of all indexes a table uses with their corresponding columns.

I am using DB2 for z/OS V9.1

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use this query to show the indexes and their columns of your tables:

```sql
SELECT IX.tbname, 
       KEY.ixname, 
       KEY.colname 
FROM   sysibm.syskeys KEY 
       JOIN sysibm.sysindexes IX 
         ON KEY.ixname = IX.name 
WHERE  IX.tbname IN ( 'SOMETABLE', 'ANOTHERTABLE' ) 
ORDER  BY IX.tbname, 
          KEY.ixname, 
          KEY.colname;
```

Comment: But sysibm.syskeys table is not exists in DB2 9.7.x

Comment: @dmitry_bond Perhaps accurate ¿for DB2 LUW?, but applicable how, to "I am using DB2 for z/OS V9.1" of the OP? FWiW: ["DB2 for Linux UNIX and Windows 9.7.0" AlternateZOSSysSchema IBM Data Server Driver configuration keyword: Set alternative schema to be searched in place of SYSIBM](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEPGG_9.7.0/com.ibm.swg.im.dbclient.config.doc/doc/r0054599.html) and [SysSchema CLI/ODBC Config Kwd: Set alternative schema to be searched in place of the SYSIBM](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_9.7.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.apdv.cli.doc/doc/r0008818.html)

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT * FROM SYSIBM.SYSKEYS WHERE IXNAME IN 
(SELECT NAME FROM SYSIBM.SYSINDEXES WHERE TBNAME = 'your_table_name')
```

I have tested it, it is giving us all the columns which are used in indexes.

Answer (score 1):

You can use below query also. it works fine if syskeys table is missing

SELECT * FROM SYSIBM.SYSINDEXCOLUSE where INDNAME IN (SELECT NAME FROM SYSIBM.SYSINDEXES si where si.TBNAME ='your_table_Name' ) ORDER BY INDNAME, COLSEQ

Answer (score -1):

I had an issue with using "KEY" as a table alias. Also, if you have multiple schemas with the same table name, use the following:

```
SELECT IX.TABLE_SCHEMA, IX.TABLE_NAME, IX.INDEX_NAME, KY.ORDINAL_POSITION, KY.COLUMN_NAME
  FROM SYSKEYS KY 
  JOIN SYSINDEXES IX ON (KY.INDEX_NAME = IX.INDEX_NAME AND KY.INDEX_SCHEMA = IX.INDEX_SCHEMA)
 WHERE IX.TBNAME = 'table-name' AND IX.TABLE_SCHEMA = 'table-schema'
 ORDER BY IX.TABLE_SCHEMA, IX.TABLE_NAME, IX.INDEX_NAME, KY.ORDINAL_POSITION
   FOR READ ONLY WITH UR
```